# Rounding a matrix, preserving row and column totals

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Wanted: (pseudo-)code for rounding a matrix in a manner that preserves row and column totals.

Problem starts with vectors, `X` and `Y`, of **non-negative integers**, with `Sum[X]==Sum[Y]`. Want to round `X×Y/Sum[X]` while preserving row and column totals.

This is a type of marriage problem. `Xa` needs to do some number of handshakes (call that number `Xa`), as do `Xb` and `Xc`; and also `Ya` `Yb` `Yc`. For whatever reason, all handshakes are between an X and a Y. Of course `Xa + Xb + Xc == Ya + Yb + Yc`. Handshaking is to be, as closely as possible, pro-rata. So want rounded `X×Y/Sum[X]` with unchanged row and column totals.

Though http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~doerr/papers/unbimatround.pdf
seems to be the answer, it has neither algorithm nor code.

Please kind readers, is there published code or pseudo-code? Or even a clear explanation of an algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Paper you posted says that a randomized rounding of The matrix, satisfy your constraints with a high probability. In the paper is sayd that it can be computed in `O(nml)` where `l` is the number of bits that are used to randomized round the matrix. So the probability can not dependent on the matrix size or the used bits.

So try the following algorithm:

```
1. For all x in your matrix do  
      r = random float number in [0,1]
      if r <= x - floor(x) then    
         x := ceil(x);  
      else  
         x := floor(x);  
2. check if the randomized rounded matrix fulfill the constrains.
   if so then end the algorithm
   else try again.
```

According to the paper, this should not take too many trys.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood the paper. Thank you. Marked as a solution — though I don’t have the points to vote for it.

Comment: I’m less sure this works. Let’s have an unrounded matrix of {{0.9,0.1},{0.1,0.9}}. Randomly round up or down, with probabilities of the fractional parts. The two good solutions are {{1,0},{0,1}} which happens with probability 0.9^4, and {{0,1},{1,0}}, which happens with probability 0.1^4. All other results of the randomisations would be rejected. So the to-nearest rounding is 9^4 = 6561 times as likely, a probability of 99.98476%, which ≠ 99%.


Or I have more deeply misunderstood.

Comment: The probability of a good solution is `0.9^4+0.1^4 = 0.6562`. So the expected number of trys is 0.6562^-1 < 2.

Comment: I agree that the algorithm is quick. But is it correct? Does it do what it says on the tin? The probability of rounding to {{1,0},{0,1}} is 99.98476%, and the probability of {{0,1},{1,0}} is almost zero. So the expected value of the rounded number ≠ the unrounded number. (Typo in previous comment: please read “99%” as “90%”.)

Comment: Im not sure I understand you right. The probability of rounding to {{1,0},{0,1}} is only 65.61% (0.9^4). If the unrounded number (a number in the matrix at the beginning) is not an inteher, the rounded number is alwas != the unrounded number. But you want only that the sum of the rows and columns of the rounded matrix and the start matrix differ from each other. to achieve this the matrix has to be rounded to {{1,0},{0,1}} or {{0,1},{1,0}}. In this example the to-nearest roundig is also a solution. but this is not alwasy right.

Comment: Having stared at the algorithm above and the paper, I am not convinced the algorithm above produces the same algorithmic complexity as the paper. Note the paper recurses on bits.