# Additive Closure of Percentages with Rounding

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have this problem of presenting a table of percentages:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| D | E | F |
+---+---+---+
| G | H | I |
+---+---+---+
```

`A`, `B`, `D`, and `E` are inputs available to me at full resolution. The following relations should also hold visually in the displayed table:

```
A + B + C + D = 100
C = A + B
F = D + E
G = A + D
B = E + H
C + F = 100
G + H = 100
I = 100
```

Now, I don't want to display the full resolution values, in fact, I want to display "whole number" percentages in the range of 0 to 100 in all table cells. My concern is that if I just calculate C, F, G, H, and I from A, B, C, and D, and then apply rounding to the table (e.g. using `toFixed(0)`), then there's a chance that the displayed values don't "add up" because of boundary conditions and uniform treatment in rounding (i.e. 0.5 always gets rounded up).

Is there a simple, algorithmic, canonical way to get the outcome I want without solving a system of (over-constrained) simultaneous equations with A, B, C, and D treated as 'knowns' and C, F, G, and H treated as 'unknowns'? It also looks kind of like a linear programming constraint satisfaction problem to me. It also feels to me like I might be overthinking it. I realize there is not a single unique solution to this problem, I'm just looking for an approach to come up with a "reasonable" answer. What do you think?

As a quick demonstration of the issue I'm worried about, lets say A = 24.5, B = 25.5, D = 25.5, and E = 24.5. 24.5 + 25.5 + 25.5 + 24.5 = 100. Rounding these with `toFixed(0)` gives A = 25, B = 26, D = 26, and E = 25. A + B + D + E = 102, G = H = C = F = 51. Fail.

Comment: I found a similar question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600499/rounding-a-matrix-preserving-row-and-column-totals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the rounding-to-sum problem.  For this case, let's start with a clear case:

```
[24.2, 25.7, 25.5, 24.6]        sum = 100
```

Round each figure; make a second list of differences `original - rounded`:

```
[24, 26, 26, 25]    sum = 101
[0.2, -0.3, -0.5, -0.4]
```

We have an excess of 1.  We want to alter the element that will be least incorrect with this altered value: that's the one with the largest negative change from rounding, `-0.5`.  This gives us

```
[24, 26, 25, 25]    sum = 100
[0.2, -0.3, +0.5, -0.4]
```

Since the sum is now 100, we're done with the alterations.  If you have a larger example with more excess or deficiency, iterate on the discrepancy until done.  For instance, in your given problem:

```
[25, 26, 26, 25]     sum = 102
[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5]
```

we would decrease two of the entries.  Since the four values are equal, this algorithm doesn't care which two we pick.  I've done this with more separated values, and have made this choice by applying percentage change: this case would decrease both 26 values to 25.